# How to add user value to top contributor web part in community site?

Tags: 2013, community-site

In OOTB community site, when a user clicks on join community, that user is added to the top contributor [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqmVm.png). I want to add the user there programmatically. How is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Top contributor Web Part is based upon gramification and reputation model and I don't think members can't simply be added as top contributors. Instead members have to earn it or rewarded/gifted reputation scores to appear as top contributors.

Moreover, Community site [doesn't expose any API at the moment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163783.aspx#bkmk_Collab)